# How to display thumbnails from multiple attachment(s) using JSON conditions, in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

With SharePoint Online, I may have a list item that may have up to 4 attachments.  Is there anyway I can setup a conditional expressional in my list (perhaps with JSON conditional logic), that checks if any attachments exists for a specific list item, display them as thumbnail images in a new column?

**My reasoning for this:**
Its very easy to add jpg photos as "add attachment" to a SharePoint list from Power Automate.  It would be awesome if SharePoint could then somehow on its end, display these attachments as thumbnail images when viewing the list.

Is this possible today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot show the list item attachments as a thumbnail image in list view using JSON formatting capabilities.

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)