# How can I show Attachment Name and preview in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

SharePoint List view:

[image: SharePoint List view]

I want to see a preview of the Attachment file in the list and the name of the attachment.

Please share if you have any ideas about this or reference.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve it using JSON formatting (asking because of tags added to this post)?

Comment: Yes, I also trying to using json-formatting, if you have any idea so Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible using SharePoint Online JSON formatting.

You cannot show the list item attachments as a thumbnail image or attachment names in list view using JSON formatting capabilities as `[$Attachments]` in JSON formatting only returns `0` or `1` based on if there are any attachments to the list items.

- 0: No attachments added to list item
- 1: One or more attachments added to list item

Similar threads:

1. [How can I add a link to list attachments using Json formatting](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304996/how-can-i-add-a-link-to-list-attachments-using-json-formatting/305000#305000)
2. [Conditional formatting if list item has attachment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/301096/conditional-formatting-if-list-item-has-attachment/301100#301100)
3. [How to display thumbnails from multiple attachment(s) using JSON conditions, in a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292740/how-to-display-thumbnails-from-multiple-attachments-using-json-conditions-in/292741#292741)

---

For workaround, you can try below:

1. Create columns in list to store the file names, etc. details of list item attachments.
2. Use a scheduled Power automate flow which runs daily (or schedule it as per your requirements).
3. Get all items in SharePoint list. You can use filters based on modified date to reduce the number of returned list items. For example: Get items which are modified after the flow ran last time (based on flow scheduled time)
4. Use get item attachments action for each list item in loop
5. Update the columns created in step 1 with required details you get from the item attachments.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful for me, but I not found my proper solution. Thanks for helping.